# re.findall() - additional criteria

Tags: python, regex

I have a part number like this:

```
part_number = '18-TX25-37 DMDFC PS'
```

When I do

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', part_number)
... ['18', 'TX25', '37', 'DMDFC', 'PS']
```

Some part numbers may have a dot such as `'18-TX25-37.25 DMDFC PS'` and my regex returns `'37'`, `'25'` etc. How can I  make it not to split at the dot and return `'37.25'` along with all other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), which is a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (that is: letters, digits, and underscores). In other words, your regular expression is searching for all groups of one or more (letters, digits, or underscores). Naturally then, when the regex engine sees `.` in the string it doesn't include it as part of the previous match.

If you want to include `.` as a valid character, you need to do so explicitly:

```
>>> import re
>>> part_number = '18-TX25-37.25 DMDFC PS'
>>> re.findall(r"[\w.]+", part_number)
['18', 'TX25', '37.25', 'DMDFC', 'PS']
```

This says to "match all groups of one or more (letters, digits, underscores, or dots)".

A subtlety: the `.` is a special character in regex, matching any one character. You don't need to escape it here because it is inside a character class (between `[]`) but if you were to use it outside of such a class you would need to precede it with a backslash.